# Do additional operations on object instantation, based on where the object has been instantiated

Tags: python

I have an API class (it will be extended and used by other classes):

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, **kwargs):
        return cls(**kwargs)
```

It is extended by:

```
class B(A):
    pass
```

Now, this is what I want: if I instantiate class B like `B(arg1=1, arg2=2)` I would like to do some **additional** operations when initializing it, like validate the `kwargs` arguments (and this code should reside in class A, *not* in B). Then, if I do `B.create(arg1=1, arg2=2)`, that validation should **not** occur.

In short, I would like to do extra operations when initializing an object only from the **outside** of the class it was defined; initalizing an object from a classmethod inside its class should **not** trigger any extra operation.

Answer (score 1):

If your "extra operations" are in the constructor then I'm afraid they'll always get run, regardless of whether you instantiate directly or through a factory. You could consider *only* allowing object creation through a set of factory methods (some with validation and some without).

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        #no extra stuff

@classmethod
def create_with_extra_stuff(cls, **kwargs):
    c = cls(**kwargs)
    c.extra_stuff()
    return c

@classmethod
def create_withuot_extra_stuff(cls, **kwargs):
    return cls(**kwargs)

@classmethod
def create(cls, with_extra_stuff = False, **kwargs):
    if with_extra_stuff:
        return cls.create_with_extra_stuff(**kwargs)
    else:
        return cls.create_without_extra_stuff(**kwargs)
```

Of course, I don't know your full use case but factory patterns are pretty much designed for this sort of thing.

This section was added after the comments were made:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, do_extra_stuff = True, **kwargs):
        if do_extra_stuff:
            self.do_extra_stuff(**kwargs)
        self.kwargs = kwargs

@classmethod
def create(cls, **kwargs):
    return cls(do_extra_stuff = False, **kwargs)
```

Further edit showing alternative:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        #lightweight constructor
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def validate(self):
        #Does not alter class variables. That would be bad in this case
        #Do stuff with self.kwargs


@classmethod
def create(cls, **kwargs):
    return cls(**kwargs)

main():
    a = A({...})
    a.validate()

    b = A.create({...})
    #b.validate() not called
```

The point is that the constructor *will* be called on construction. The trick then is to decide what additional stuff needs to be selective called.

Comment: The `classmethod`s are placed inside the `A` class. Also, I can do extra stuff _after_ I have instantiated the class, but that "extra stuff" should be done on the `kwargs` supplied at instantiation. It's a little bit twisted.

Comment: Perhaps then the "extra stuff" needs to be implemented in another class method before the object is instantiated. You kind of have to unless you have another parameter in the constructor which is used to signal whether "extra stuff" should be done or not.

Comment: I can add the "extra stuff" in a classmethod, but then based on what I will call that classmethod at instantiation time?

Comment: Now we enter the same debate as with the other answer...Isn't there a more "bullet proof" solution to this?

Comment: Yip. Document your API :)

Comment: And if the user is unaware? He can break things by assigning, say `False` to that particular kwarg.

Comment: Then just do as @ndpu suggests and have your validation as a separate method called after construction (or not called as the case may be)

Comment: What happens if many objects are instantiated in a loop? By setting a class variable, when instantiating one object, the class variable may already be altered by some other object instantiation; it does not guarantee this works the same for every scenario.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48260/discussion-between-will-and-andrei-horak)

Answer (score 1):

You can use additional argument to distinguish method of class initialisation:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, __a_validate=True, **kwargs):
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        if __a_validate:
            print 'do validation'

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, **kwargs):
        return cls(__a_validate=False, **kwargs)
```

Demo:

```
>>> B.create(arg1=1, arg2=2)
<__main__.B object at 0x9b82f4c>

>>> B(arg1=1, arg2=2)
do validation
<__main__.B object at 0x9b7bbcc>
```

**update for comments:**

This is another solution. You can modify class attribute in `create` method, for example set `validate` function to `None`, call constructor and then set `validate` back to original state:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        if self.validate:
            self.validate(kwargs)

    def validate(self, kwargs):
        print 'do validation'

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, **kwargs):
        tmp = cls.validate
        cls.validate = None
        instance = cls(**kwargs)
        cls.validate = tmp
        return instance
```

Comment: It's great, but what if it happens that one of my `kwargs` really is named `validate`? I could name it `_validate`, as it is less likely for someone to pass that kind of an argument, but still it isn't bullet proof.

Comment: @AndreiHorak added some undrscores to make this flag hard to appear in kwargs. Yes, it is not bulletproof but sufficient in this case i think...

Comment: This approach is the simplest and (kind of) the cleanest, but it does require that the user of the class is aware that he should not use that specific kwarg, which in most cases, he is not. Isn't there another way of doing this?

Comment: I agree, this is kinda what I was aiming for too. One can assume that the API is documented for the user to understand how to use it.

Comment: @AndreiHorak i've updated answer with one more solution, but i think first one is better, just set flag name to some 'hard to apper in user kwargs name' and document it in class docstring...

Comment: I thought of using this, but I believe that setting and unsetting a class variable, especially if multiple instances are created, has a negative impact over the script's performance.